# Got three "Variable not in scope" errors in my Haskell code while doing module expressions for guards

Tags: haskell

I have the following Haskell code with guards which are intended to print the following Strings when I entered a number for my function, meaning when it is divided by either 2, 3, or 5 it was intended to print a string containing the number in Spanish, otherwise printing "Nada".

```
compositeNumber::Integer -> String
compositeNumber x 
    |(x % 2 == 0) = "Dos"
    |(x % 3 == 0) = "Tres"
    |(x % 5 == 0) = "Cinco"
    |otherwise = "Nada"
    
main = print$ compositeNumber 4;
```

However, when I went to run my code, I got this error.

```
main.hs:3:9: error:
    Variable not in scope: (%) :: Integer -> Bool -> Bool
  |
3 |     |(x % 2 == 0) = "Dos"
  |         ^

main.hs:4:9: error:
    Variable not in scope: (%) :: Integer -> Bool -> Bool
  |
4 |     |(x % 3 == 0) = "Tres"
  |         ^

main.hs:5:9: error:
    Variable not in scope: (%) :: Integer -> Bool -> Bool
  |
5 |     |(x % 5 == 0) = "Cinco"
  |         ^
```

I am still new to Haskell and I am currently learning it, and there are probably some things in the language which are unfamiliar to me. I would really appreciate it if you would help me find out how to fix this error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell does not use `%` for modulus. Use the `rem` or `mod` functions instead. That is, replace expressions like `x % 2` with `rem x 2` or `` x `rem` 2 ``.

(As for the difference between `rem` and `mod`, my understanding is that they differ mostly with respect to their behaviour with negative numbers. When you only need to deal with positive numbers, `rem` is usually recommended as it is slightly faster.)

Comment: Oh, maybe I might have misread some of the Haskell basic information while learning it. I finally got my code to work, thanks! :)

Comment: You’re welcome @anonymous! (Note that if it helps you, you can mark this answer as ‘accepted’ with the green tick next to the arrows.)